# Is Clara Oswald still the Impossible Girl?

Tags: doctor-who

When we first meet Clara "Oswin" Oswald in *Asylum of the Daleks*, she is "The Impossible Girl." Now, in the current series, she doesn't seem as "impossible" as she did with Smith's Doctor where she kept dying and re-appearing.

Is she still "The Impossible Girl" in the current on air series with Peter Capaldi, or has this been resolved? If so, where is this explained in the plot or story arc?

Comment: In a show filled with timey-wimey stuff, do the words "still" and "now" have any meaning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mystery of Clara has already been resolved in the season 7 finale (with Matt Smith, the 11th Doctor). In the episode *The Name of the Doctor*,

> Clara jumped into the timeline of The Doctor (this timeline was in physical Form inside the TARDIS grave of The Doctor) to save him from The Great Intelligence (who successfully rewrote Doctor's timeline turning his every victory into failure).

That's why she keep dying and re-appearing in The Doctor's life

> (she even talked to the 1st Doctor when he was stealing his TARDIS).

Comment: Yes, but what does that mean for her now? Is she one of those incarnations, or is she the "real" her? We know what happened in *The Name of the Doctor*, but the question is what's her status now.

Comment: @Avner The OP specifically asked about her dying and reappearing thing. So, this answers that.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: if you’d like an answer to your question, feel free to ask it as a question.

Comment: @Avner, after Clara rescued the Doctor throughout time, the Doctor rescued her from his timeline. She's no longer fractured.

Comment: @BrianS are you talking about the scene when they introduce J. Hurt?